# Symfony 3.4 Sonata editable number

Tags: symfony, x-editable, sonata

Do you know how to make x-editable accept decimal numbers? i can only choose integers!

I'm using it with Symfony 3.4 and Sonata.

Sonata Admin

```
->add('totalAe', 'currency', array('label' => 'AE', 'currency' => 'EUR', 'locale' => 'fr_FR', 'editable' => true))
```

Entity

```
/**
 * @var decimal
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="total_ae", type="decimal", precision=12, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $totalAe;
```

YML

```
    totalAe:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 12
        scale: 2
        column: total_ae
```

[image: Sonata list]

Thank you!